# Meaning of WADL

Tags: wadl

Today i read the description of [WADL from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)

> The Web Application Description Language (WADL) is an XML-based file
>   format that provides a machine-readable description of HTTP-based web
>   applications.

Here what is the meaning of "Machine readable description of HTTP based web applications"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine-readable means that it is written in a way that a program can easily parse it into a well-defined structure.

This way tools like [wadl2java](http://wadl.java.net/) can generate "client stub", which is source code that allows programmers to interact with the web application.